# [SOLVED] pcl_ros: how to find cloud frame

Tags: pcl, transform, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,
I am using pcl_ros package, with pcl 1.6 and ROS groovy.
I am subscribing to a PointCloud2 topic, using a callback like this:

void MainWindow::xtionCloudCallback(const pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGB::ConstPtr& cloud)

is it possible to get the cloud frame? if I transform the cloud using a TransformListener tf, e.g.:

pcl_ros::transformPointCloud("/map", *cloud, *tcloud, tf);

this function is able to retrieve the cloud frame in some way, how do I get it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190850/%5Bsolved%5D-pcl_ros:-how-to-find-cloud-frame/) by [madmage](https://answers.ros.org/users/11946/madmage/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2014-08-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any stamped (i.e. containing timing/transform info) message will have a [header](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html) (e.g. [PointCloud](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud.html)) that contains the relevant timestamp and frame id.

`cloud->header.frame_id`

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmage](https://answers.ros.org/users/11946/madmage/) on 2014-08-22**:
thanks, I was thinking I had a pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGB from the PCL library, not a message from ROS (with a header) with the same classname

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-08-22**:
pcl::PointCloud<> has a header with stamp and frame_id as well, however those are not compatible the ROS message format, so you have to use the converter utilities in pcl_ros.